# Linear regression model accuracy is always 1.0 in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

> ***Problem:***
>
> I am building a model that will predict housing price. So, firstly I
> decided to build a Linear regression model in Tensorflow. But when I
> start training I see that my accuracy is always 1

*I am new to machine learning. Please, someone, tell me what's going wrong I can't figure it out. I searched in google but doesn't find any answer that solves my problem.*

Here's my code

```
df_train = df_train.loc[:, ['OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageArea', 'SalePrice']]
df_X = df_train.loc[:, ['OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageArea']]
df_Y = df_train.loc[:, ['SalePrice']]
df_yy = get_dummies(df_Y)
print("Shape of df_X: ", df_X.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_X, df_yy, test_size=0.15)
X_train = np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.float32)
X_test = np.asarray(X_test).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test).astype(np.float32)


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_of_features])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_of_features, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

prediction = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)
num_epochs = 20000
# calculating loss
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y, logits=prediction))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(cost)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, axis=1), tf.argmax(y, axis=1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (epoch, train_accuracy))
        optimizer.run(feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})

print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
X: X_test, y: y_test}))
```

Output is:

```
step 0, training accuracy 1
step 100, training accuracy 1
step 200, training accuracy 1
step 300, training accuracy 1
step 400, training accuracy 1
step 500, training accuracy 1
step 600, training accuracy 1
step 700, training accuracy 1
............................
............................
step 19500, training accuracy 1
step 19600, training accuracy 1
step 19700, training accuracy 1
step 19800, training accuracy 1
step 19900, training accuracy 1
test accuracy 1
```

***EDIT:***
I changed my cost function to this

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(prediction-y, 2))/(2*1241)
```

But still my output is always 1.

***EDIT 2:***
*In response to lejlot comment:*
Thanks lejlot. I changed my accuracy code to this

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/hpp1")
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    if epoch % 5:
        s = sess.run(merged_summary, feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
        writer.add_summary(s, epoch)
    sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
    if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
        c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
        print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
            "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))

print("Optimization Finished!")
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
print("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')
```

But the output is all **nan**
**Output:**

```
....................................
Epoch: 19900 cost= nan W= nan b= nan
Epoch: 19950 cost= nan W= nan b= nan
Epoch: 20000 cost= nan W= nan b= nan
Optimization Finished!
Training cost= nan W= nan b= nan
```

Comment: the main problem is **there is no such thing** as accuracy for regression. You should be reporting cost value over time, and not accuracy (which will always be 1, as it is argmax over 1 dimension, for both target and prediction).

Comment: Hi, lejlot Thank you very much for your answer. I changed my code but my b and W are now null. Please see EDIT 2 of my question

Comment: Hi, lejlot I just changed the learning rate to a lower value and now model is learning and W and b are no longer null. Thank you very much lejlot.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use linear regression, but you actually use [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). Take a look at [`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy): it outputs a probability distribution, i.e. a vector of numbers that sum up to `1`. In your case, the vector has `size=1`, hence it always outputs `[1]`.

Here are two examples that will help you see the difference: [linear regression](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.ipynb) and [logistic regression](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.ipynb).

Comment: Hi, Maxim! thanks for your answer. I added an edit to my question after your answer.

Comment: I didn't say it explicitly, but I meant that you should get rid of all elements that belong to logistic regression rather then linear regression, that includes `correct_prediction` and `accuracy` as well, as suggested by lejlot.